MiKTeX Console Error: Cannot Retrieve Attributes for Directory 'C:\Windows\System32\hidapi.dll'
enter image description here
Hi everyone,
I'm encountering an issue with MiKTeX on my Windows 11 machine. Whenever I try to open the MiKTeX Console (both user and admin versions), I receive an error saying:
MiKTeX cannot retrieve attributes for the directory 'C:\Windows\System32\hidapi.dll'
I've tried several things to resolve this issue:
Verified that the hidapi.dll file exists in C:\Windows\System32.
Ran the sfc /scannow command to repair any corrupted system files (it did find and repair some, but the issue persists).
Ensured that both users and administrators have full control over the hidapi.dll file.
Reinstalled MiKTeX completely.
Ran MiKTeX Console as an administrator.
In addition, I'm also facing issues in Visual Studio Code when trying to compile LaTeX documents, where it throws the following error: spawn latexmk ENOENT.
Despite these steps, the problem persists, and I'm unable to use the MiKTeX Console or compile LaTeX documents.
Has anyone experienced a similar issue on Windows 11 or have any suggestions for how to fix this?
Thanks in advance for your help!
I tried the following steps, expecting them to resolve the issue or at least allow me to run MiKTeX Console and compile LaTeX documents:
Checked the file: I verified that the hidapi.dll file exists in C:\Windows\System32\ and expected that fixing permissions or missing files could solve the issue.
Ran sfc /scannow: I used this system file checker command to repair any corrupted system files. It did find and repair some, but the problem with MiKTeX persists.
Ensured correct file permissions: I ensured that both users and administrators have full control over the hidapi.dll file.
Reinstalled MiKTeX: I completely reinstalled MiKTeX, hoping that a fresh installation would fix the issue.
Ran MiKTeX Console as admin: I tried running MiKTeX Console as an administrator to bypass any potential permissions issue.
Unfortunately, none of these attempts worked, and I continue to get the same error.
Additionally, I'm facing an issue in Visual Studio Code where I'm trying to compile LaTeX documents, and it throws the following error: spawn latexmk ENOENT.
What I expected: I was expecting that by fixing permissions, repairing system files, or reinstalling MiKTeX, I would be able to run the MiKTeX Console and compile LaTeX documents in VSCode without any errors.
Has anyone experienced a similar issue on Windows 11 or have any suggestions for how to fix this?
Thanks in advance for your help!

I also got a similar issue but in my case it is npm.cmd. When I attempt to open miktex-console, I get the error message: "MiKTeX cannot retrieve attributes for the directory 'C:\Users{myname}\AppData\Roaming\npm\npm.cmd'."
